# Can I pull Shopware 6 Plugins configurations from the .env file (like in Magento)?

Tags: environment-variables, shopware6

In Magento 2 we store config data which is only relevant for production in the `env.php` - so it is not included in DB dumps and such.

Is this possible in Shopware 6 ?

For example, if I have a plugin config like

`JopsoMonitoring.config.sentryEnvironment` I can already call
`bin/console system:config:set JopsoMonitoring.config.sentryEnvironment dev'

But can I also write something like

`JopsoMonitoring.config.sentryEnvironment` in the `.env`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's currently not supported, but it's an interesting idea. The `SystemConfigService` relies on the settings being stored in the database so the service would have to be refactored to account for environment variables. A quick solution would be to write a CLI command implementation that uses `dotenv` to read the config settings, maybe detectable by a certain prefix, and persists the values via the `SystemConfigService`. That command could then be automated to be executed after deployment.

If third-party tool are an option, you could have a look at `shopware-cli` that comes with a [command to push config setting from a yml file](https://sw-cli.fos.gg/commands/project/#shopware-cli-project-config-push).

Answer (score 0):

FroshTools support this feature now

https://github.com/FriendsOfShopware/FroshTools#override-system_config-with-config-files